# How can I shut down Windows?

Tags: delphi, winapi, system-shutdown

How can I in a Delphi application (7, trying to port it to 2010) force the system (XP or 7) to shut down?

Comment: Almost duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57868352/delphi-reboot-windows

Answer (score 5):

Look at Zarco Gajic's tip from About.com, "[Shut down/reboot Windows 2000/XP/NT](http://delphi.about.com/cs/adptips2003/a/bltip0503_5.htm)."

Comment: Fantastic, very ruthless, this will save my client a lot of electricity.

Comment: @herman: If there is a chance that the system is running on remote desktop this may not be enough. You need to test, but I remember I had to add special code for an internal app to optionally use the `WTSShutdownSystem()` function, to actually shut down the PC without any request for confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
  ShellExecute(0, nil, 'cmd.exe', '/C shutdown /s', nil, SW_HIDE);
```

Do not forget to add ShellApi to USES.

This code runs command shutdown with parameter /s in command line.

[Shutdown command](https://www.lifewire.com/shutdown-command-2618100)