# Delphi reboot Windows

Tags: delphi

I'm using Windows 10 and I am logged in as Administrator.

When I try to reboot the system, all it does is it logs me off.

```
ExitWindowsEx(EWX_REBOOT and EWX_FORCE, 0);
```

Can someone please tell me why is this not rebooting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was looking for a better solution to the one I had done about 5 years ago (posted below), I needed to do some tweaking for it to run on latest Delphi, older Delphi versions simply use Windows.AdjustTokenPrivileges.  Code below is tried and tested since windows XP. **Be careful - it works, make sure you save your work before running!**

```
//Uses WinApi.Windows on Latest Delphi 10.3.2
function MyExitWindows(RebootParam: Longword): Boolean;
var
  TTokenHd: THandle;
  TTokenPvg: TTokenPrivileges;


cbtpPrevious: DWORD;
  rTTokenPvg: TTokenPrivileges;
  pcbtpPreviousRequired: DWORD;
  tpResult: Boolean;
const
  SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME = 'SeShutdownPrivilege';
begin
  if Win32Platform = VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT then
  begin
    tpResult := OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(),
      TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES or TOKEN_QUERY,
      TTokenHd);
    if tpResult then
    begin
      tpResult := LookupPrivilegeValue(nil,
                                       SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME,
                                       TTokenPvg.Privileges[0].Luid);
      TTokenPvg.PrivilegeCount := 1;
      TTokenPvg.Privileges[0].Attributes := SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
      cbtpPrevious := SizeOf(rTTokenPvg);
      pcbtpPreviousRequired := 0;
      if tpResult then
        //Older Delphi - replace the WinApi. to read WinApi.AdjustTokenPrivileges
        WinApi.Windows.AdjustTokenPrivileges(TTokenHd,
                                      False,
                                      TTokenPvg,
                                      cbtpPrevious,
                                      rTTokenPvg,
                                      pcbtpPreviousRequired);
    end;
  end;
  Result := ExitWindowsEx(RebootParam, 0);
end;

//Examples
//Shutdown the computer

MyExitWindows(EWX_POWEROFF or EWX_FORCE);

//Reboot the computer
MyExitWindows(EWX_REBOOT or EWX_FORCE);
```

Answer (score 8):

So it seems that even though I am a administrator I need to set the rights with the following function

```
function NTSetPrivilege(sPrivilege: string; bEnabled: Boolean): Boolean;
var
  hToken: THandle;
  TokenPriv: TOKEN_PRIVILEGES;
  PrevTokenPriv: TOKEN_PRIVILEGES;
  ReturnLength: Cardinal;
begin
  Result := True;
  // Only for Windows NT/2000/XP and later.
  if not (Win32Platform = VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT) then Exit;
  Result := False;

  // obtain the processes token
  if OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(),
    TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES or TOKEN_QUERY, hToken) then
  begin
    try
      // Get the locally unique identifier (LUID) .
      if LookupPrivilegeValue(nil, PChar(sPrivilege),
        TokenPriv.Privileges[0].Luid) then
      begin
        TokenPriv.PrivilegeCount := 1; // one privilege to set

        case bEnabled of
          True: TokenPriv.Privileges[0].Attributes  := SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
          False: TokenPriv.Privileges[0].Attributes := 0;
        end;

        ReturnLength := 0; // replaces a var parameter
        PrevTokenPriv := TokenPriv;

        // enable or disable the privilege

        AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, False, TokenPriv, SizeOf(PrevTokenPriv),
          PrevTokenPriv, ReturnLength);
      end;
    finally
      CloseHandle(hToken);
    end;
  end;
  // test the return value of AdjustTokenPrivileges.
  Result := GetLastError = ERROR_SUCCESS;
  if not Result then
    raise Exception.Create(SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
end;
```

like this :

```
procedure TMain.Neustart1Click(Sender: TObject);
const
    SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME = 'SeShutdownPrivilege';
begin
  NTSetPrivilege(SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME, True);

  ExitWindowsEx(EWX_REBOOT or EWX_FORCE, 0);
end;
```

Now it works.

Comment: The error handling is badly broken here. You need to detect errors by checking return values. And GetLastError must be called immediately after an API failure. If you call other functions in between then the error code may be modified. And that happens here with the call to CloseHandle.

Comment: Also it's pointless to have a function that either returns True or raises an exception! Use Win32Check to make all your error handling simple.

Comment: MSDN mentioned needing the privilege for 15+ years already, it's nothing that has changed neither recently nor unexpectedly. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-exitwindowsex

Comment: Source of that code is https://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/en/showcode.php?id=1177 with all its inconsistency

Comment: both of you are right... and I never said that I wrote this code, I found this online. But perhaps you two might edit and fix the code then ...  thank you